# Why my discord bot cant edit him embed messages?

Tags: javascript, discord

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    let channel = reaction.message.channel;
    let message = reaction.message;
    const msgembed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
    if (reaction.emoji.id === '795433333799426058' && !user.bot) {
        const embed = msgembed
        .setColor("GREEN");
        message.edit(embed);
    }
    if (reaction.emoji.id === '795433533334380722' && !user.bot) {
        const embed = msgembed
        .setColor("RED");
        message.edit(embed);
    }
});
```

I wrote this code to my bot to edit embed messages. but there is a problem.
If the message is sent after the bot restarts, it can edit the embed message.
If it sent the embed message before the bot restarts, it does not edit the message and does not show any errors.
Why the messages sent by the bot before rebooting aren't edited. How do I edit the embed messages the bot sends before it restarts.

Comment: hey i need help